# Ocaml print to file with newline

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to print the contents of a file to a new file line by line. However After running this function, only the last line of the input file is written to the output file.

```
let in_channel = open_in inFile in
try
  while true do
    let line = input_line in_channel in
    let oc = open_out outFile in    

    fprintf oc "%s\n" line;  

    close_out oc;              
  done
  with End_of_file ->
    close_in in_channel
```

What am I doing wrong? I am inputting the newline in the printf statement, so I am very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALopen_out:

> ```
> val open_out : string -> out_channel
> ```
>
> Open the named file for writing, and return a new output channel on that file, positioned at the beginning of the file. **The file is truncated to zero length if it already exists.** It is created if it does not already exists.

You're calling `open_out` repeatedly inside the loop. For every line you read, you first truncate `outFile` back to length 0 before writing to it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the loop, printing to the file, appending it to the end?

Comment: The printing part in the loop is fine. Why don't you simply move the `open_out` part out of the loop (just like your `open_in` call is outside of the loop)?

Comment: It results in a "syntax error" pointing to the end of the .ml file which is nothing. I am extremely confused.

Comment: @Baily You're missing a `;` between `in_channel` and `close_out`.

Comment: just saw that, didn't fix the issue sadly.

Comment: @Baily Then that's not the whole code. I can't debug code I can't see.

Comment: @Baily I've reverted your edit because it changes the question substantially. However, the issue in that code was the `;` after `close_out oc`.

Comment: adding the ; after close_out oc did not fix the issues, the previous code I pushed which you edited still does not work, I am wondering what resources I should use to further debug this issue?

Comment: @Baily Oops, I got confused. I meant the `;` after `close_in in_channel`. Removing that made the error go away.